# Elementor header bug width

Tags: wordpress, header, elementor

I've been having a problem with Elementor for weeks now. In every site I'm making, when I create the header and set "position:absolute" and then "position:fixed" (after scrolling with jQuery), if I try to resize the window in the floating version, the header shortens from only even if I set "width: 100%;" to the header. I see that Elementor automatically gives an inline style "width: 203px...". What's going on?
I attach some screenshots.

https://martinibus.studiosastra.com

What is happening?
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbKTT.png)
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R27va.png)

I tried to change the style inline but still the same problem remains.